# How could I check my regexp value it correct?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check that value provided by user is correct and correspond to the following format `47:VkqFAUUZ`, `5:dkqdAU3d`. The first path is number and the second part is string of 7-14 length?

**EDIT**: the second part could be the following symbols `A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _-`

Comment: The number part have to be at max 2 digits or it can have any length?

Comment: Any length.. I guess :P

Comment: No, the number part could be one or two digits

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
^\d{1,2}:[A-Za-z0-9_-]{7,14}$
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1yqaavpu/3/)

Comment: @karthikmanchala hahaha.. do you realize that those are two different tests? They are separated.

Comment: @karthikmanchala Besides, your regex fails when applied with JS(which is what the OP wants), run this on you console: `Boolean("384753847538:h37fh3847fh3487f83fh".match(/\d{1,2}:[\w-]{7,14}/))`  or try to check the input [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1yqaavpu/4/). ;P

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^\d{1,2}:[\w-]{7,14}$`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yM4eA4/4)

If you aslo want to restrict the length of number to `x`(any integer) you can use `\d{x}:[\w-]{7,14}`

Comment: the number part could either be one or two digits. Is it ok `\d{2}` or I need `\d{1,2}` ?

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that `\w` embraces `_` and digits too.

Comment: Thanks.. also. your pattern does not work with OP's tests since you have `^` and `$`.. which restrict comma separated matches.. dont you think?

Comment: @Touffy I did not find any documentation saying so.. can you tell me in which flavor it happens?